# chart.js sum of the last 3h datavalues in a line chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js, momentjs, linechart

i have a question in chart.js
I have a line-chart with y-axis is integer-Type and x-axis is time-Type in hour.
I have a dataset with 10 datapoints.

Now i only want the sum of the last 3 hours.
I know, how to sum all of these, but not to select specific ones, without needing to write some big code.

So is there any simple solution built into chart.js or moment.js?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know am I fully understand what you are asking about. But if you have an array (datapoints) and you need to take some amount of last elements, you can use **arr.slice(-3)**.

Check this example with chart.js:

```js
let ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'datapoints',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 15, 2, 3, 7, 10, 5, 8],
            borderWidth: 2
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});

let nLastElements = 3;
let sum = myChart.data.datasets[0]
          .data
          .slice(-nLastElements)
          .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

console.log("Sum of last " + nLastElements + " elements: " + sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Helped me a lot. But i had to reverse the array. After that it was like it should be :-)

Comment: Well, you can use slice(positiveNumber) :)

Comment: I've tested it. But this was not the right result. maybe because my x-axis goes from past-time on the left side (nullpoint) to present-time on the right side.

Comment: If there isn't anything else to help with in this question, please mark the answer that you accepted it. It will help me a lot)